# Lua: getting global function failing after loading file

Tags: c++, lua

I'm attempting to call a function inside of a lua file called test2.lua
This is the contents of test2.lua:

```
function abc(path)
 t = {}
 table.insert(t, "a")
 return t
end
```

As you can see it takes a single input and returns a string.

Here is my C code. It's pretty simple. However my call getglobal in order to call that function does not work... lua_getglobal says it isn't a function when I test it... Any reason why this is? Shouldn't abc be a global function returnable inside of the source file? Why then does it only find nil for this global?

```
L = lua_open();
luaL_openlibs(L);
luaL_loadfile(L, "src/test2.lua");

lua_getglobal(L, "abc");

lua_pushstring(L, "coollll");

int error = 0;
if ((error = lua_pcall(L, 1, 1, 0)) == 0)
{
    std::cout << "cool";
}
```

EDIT:

calling lua_getglobal is causing my program to break control regardless of using loadfile or dofile... any idea why?

[lua_getglobal crashing program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754778/lua-getglobal-crashing-program)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `luaL_loadfile()` reads, parses, and compiles the named Lua file. It does not execute any of its content. This is important in your case because the statement `function abc(path)`...`end` has no visible effect until it is executed. The `function` keyword as you've used it is equivalent to writing

```
abc = function(path)  
  t = {}
  table.insert(t, "a")
  return t
end
```

In this form, it is clearer that the variable named `abc` is not actually assigned a value until the code executes.

When `luaL_loadfile()` returns, it has pushed an anonymous function on the top of the Lua stack that is the result of compiling your file. You need to call it, and `lua_pcall()` will do the trick. Replace your reference to `luaL_loadfile()` with this:

```
if (luaL_loadfile(L, "src/test2.lua") || lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0)) {
    // do something with the error
}
```

At this point, test2.lua has been executed and any functions it defined or other global variables it modified are available.

This is a common enough idiom, that the function `luaL_dofile()` is provided to load and call a file by name.

There is a second, more subtle issue in your code as presented. The function `abc()` uses a variable named `t`, but you should be aware that `t` as used is a global variable. You probably meant to write `local t = {}` at the top of `abc()`.

Comment: Okay. So I understand well the concept that you must run the file before you can access the function until the code is executed. all well and good. I changed the loadfile to the dofile. however I have a new problem. I'll probably create a new question for it, but lua_getglobal is breaking. Happening regardless of using loadfile or dofile, when calling lua_getglobal(L, "trans"); it crashes in luaS_newlstr... after calling the getfield... :/

Answer (score 3):

It's not enough to call `luaL_loadfile`: this puts a chunk onto the stack. Either follow up with `luaL_[p]call` to execute the chunk (thus making the function available), or use `luaL_dofile`.