# Lua/C binding, binding from lua

Tags: c, binding, lua

I'm currently building a lua event system (in lua), however I want to be able to fire events from C too, I was wanting to bind a C function to a lua function, such that the C function could fire events in lua, I was planning to use the:

```
lua_register
```

function; however I can't seem to find a way to bind my lua function like this, it would seem I'm in need of a lua function that does the same, but from the lua side, I was thinking about making some hack, by binding a C function into lua, that simply calls 'lua_register', but this seems a bit unsafe to me.

So what should I do instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not fully sure I understand what you've asked for. So allow me to explain what I think your question is.

You have some Lua code. In that Lua code, you have a system. This system is, at some point, given one or more events. For each event that it is given, it calls some function or functions that were registered to be called when that particular event was given.

So, this system has two basic functions:

```
EventSystem:RegisterEventHandler(EventName, Func);
EventSystem:FireEvent(EventName, ...);
```

The `RegisterEventHandler` method will associate the given `Func` with the given `EventName`, such that when `FireEvent` is called later, `Func` will be called if the `EventName` given to `FireEvent` is the same one `Func` was registered with.

Now you want to have C code be able to register C functions as event handlers. So it's time to talk about registering C functions in Lua.

The C API call `lua_register` is actually a macro. It creates a C function on the Lua stack, then puts it in the global table, using the string index given to `lua_register`. These are two *separate* operations; `lua_register` is just a convenience function that makes them the same.

What you want is to call `RegisterEventHandler` from C code, passing the C function as the third parameter (remember: the first parameter is `self`, because I called `RegisterEventHandler` with `:` instead of `.`. If you're using a global event system rather than an object oriented one, you only have two parameters). This requires two things:

1. You have to know how to call Lua functions from C code.
2. You have to know how to pass a C function to Lua code.

**Step 1:** It's all done via the Lua stack (I'll assume you know how that works. If not, I have a [pretty substantial answer that explains most everything you might want to know about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511432/managing-stack-with-lua-and-c/6514692#6514692)).

The first thing you need to do is get the function you want to call onto the stack. To do that, you need to get an event system object (again, if your event system is global, just get the global table) and push it onto the stack. How you do that depends on where your event system objects are stored. Presumably you can get them through the global table.

Once you have the event system on the stack, you just index it with the `"RegisterEventHandler"` string, which will return to you the Lua function we need.

Next, we push our parameters onto the stack, from first to last. The first parameter is the event system object; it's probably still on the stack, so we can copy it. The second is the event name, and that's easy to push. The third is the C function. Which leads us to:

**Step 2:** `lua_register` is not going to get the job done. It's too heavy handed; it puts the C function in the global table. We need it on the stack. So we must use a lower level function: `lua_pushcclosure`. Or `lua_pushcfunction`, if you don't need upvalues.

These functions take a C function, wrap it up in Lua, and push it onto the Lua stack.

Now that the 3 parameters are on the stack, we can call the event registration function with a call to `lua_pcall`. Or your favorite Lua function calling function; however you wish to do it. Lua will consume the 3 parameters and the function itself, so that they are no longer on the stack.

And since the event registration function probably doesn't return values, the stack will be where it was right before we got the function onto the stack (but not before we started, depending on how much cleanup was done while getting the function).

After this, your C function will be registered with the event handler for that event name.

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint you, but what I am actually looking for is a way to call 'FireEvent' from C, as I want my lua system to be aware of the game engines state.

Comment: @Skeen: Then just call it. Do what I suggested, only with different names and parameters. And of course, not creating a C function in Lua. Just get the function you want to call on the Lua stack, then put the parameters you want to use on the stack, and then call the function.